# How can I add an attribute to every `p` element in quilljs?

Tags: javascript, quill, parchment

How can I add an attribute to every `Block` element in quilljs?

I know that I can extend a `Block`, but is it possible to add an attribute even when pressing "Enter" on the keyboard?

```
let Block = Quill.import('blots/block');

class ParaBlot extends Block {
   static create(value) {
      let node = super.create();
      return node;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an attribute like style or class to every Block element,

We could extend the default [block blot](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment/blob/master/src/blot/block.ts) element from the [parchment](https://github.com/quilljs/parchment) lib,

Just like you are already doing, we import the `Block Blot` element and we extend the `create(...)` method to edit the node's attributes using the `setAttribute` function.

Here i'll be adding a border and a customBlock class for example.

Finnaly we override the default BlockBlot with ours

```
const BlockBlot = Quill.import('blots/block');

class CustomBlockBlot extends BlockBlot {
    static create(value) {
        const node = super.create(value);
        node.setAttribute('style', 'border: 1px solid lightgrey');
        node.setAttribute('class', 'customBlock');
        return node;
    }
}
Quill.register('formats/block', CustomBlockBlot);
```

Here is a demo [https://codepen.io](https://codepen.io/simplicitysstrength/pen/BaoOvKm)

This code block has to run before the target Quill instance is created 
with `new Quill(...)`

We should also consider that it isn't able to change formatting dynamically although i believe we could backup the `Delta` and create a fresh new Quill instance with these new defaults.

Another good post about this [implement-custom-editor-for-quill-blot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125342/implement-custom-editor-for-quill-blot)

Comment: Currently in the process of learning Parchment x Quill, 
i'll be grateful for any advice on best practices